# php retrieved data to populate DIV in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need advise. Below is what I already have and my requirement.

MySQL table has 4 columns.
I'm using php to retrieve data on all rows in a single string(CODE A).

I have a DIV setup in HTML (CODE B - as in below IMAGE)

I want to be able to use the retrieved data into the DIV setup to create multiple IMAGEs (something like a for-loop in html?) - How can I achieve my requirement?

How should I do this?

CODE A

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"]; 
    $itemdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["datemade"])); 
    $dataString .= $id.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$lastname.'|'.$itemdate.'||'; 
}
```

CODE B

```
 <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="box-1" class="box">
        <gt_descA>Teak Chair</gt_descA><gt_descC>$75.34</gt_descC>
            <img id="image-1" src="imagez/designs/thumbs/0/teak_chair001.jpg"/>
                <span class="caption simple-caption">
                <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
                <div class="minibuttonC"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </span>
        </div>
        </div>
```

IMAGE (DIV setup)

[image]

I want to be able to achieve this from the retrieved data & the DIV setup
[image]

Comment: what exactly u want to do ? i didn't got your point ?

Comment: I want to create the images using the php values in HTML.

Comment: ok, so u have id,first name,last name and item date variables in php how do u want to create image with this. what will be the structure ?

Comment: you see the image - "Teak Chair" = first name VARIABLE |  "$75.34" is last name VARIABLE and Grey box = item VARIABLE.

Answer (score 1):

Put the html code in the php loop.

Eg.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
$id = $row["id"]; 
$firstname = $row["firstname"];
$lastname = $row["lastname"]; 
$itemdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["datemade"])); 
$dataString .= $id.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$lastname.'|'.$itemdate.'||'; 
?>


    <div id="box-1" class="box">
    <gt_descA>Teak Chair</gt_descA><gt_descC>$75.34</gt_descC>
        <img id="image-1" src="imagez/designs/thumbs/0/teak_chair001.jpg"/>
            <span class="caption simple-caption">
            <div class="minibuttonR"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
            <div class="minibuttonL"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
            <div class="minibuttonC"><a href="index.html" onClick="gotowebpage('11');"></a></div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </span>
    </div>
<?php

}
```

Comment: use <?=$dataString?>,to print your php variables in the html code.